# Why do global filters get called before controller filters in MVC application?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

According to this [article](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.filterscope%28v=vs.98%29.aspx) the global filters get called first, this is especially weird for exception handling, when custom errors is enabled and an exception gets thrown the global custom errors filter gets called before a controller filter gets called. Why would it not go to the most detailed first?

Comment: Because you may want to have a global filter and have the option of overriding it at the Controller level. That makes more sense, doesn't it?

If you do it the other way around, the global filter will override everything. Then, what's the point of having filters at the Controller level?

Comment: I think you would still be able to do that, you would just invert the location of the logic. If it went the other way I think that would be a bit more intuitive and also you would be able to include details for the global filter to use if it needed to.

Comment: Can you explain to me how that would be possible? When filter A overwrites filter B, it means filter A gets executed instead of filter B. If global filters where supposed to be get called last, they would overwrite all the other filters at the action or controller level. Which means they would be executed instead of all the other filters. Is that clear now?

Comment: The filters are executed in a chain in a specified order even if one has resulted in work - Its not/never is instead of. So when the global filter handles an action the controller filter still executes. That is how you are currently able to override the global filter at the controller level - if the order of operation was inverted each filter would have the opportunity to or not to override the previous one just  as it is now.